# DRY for displaying meteor templates for different urls

Tags: dry, meteor

I am having trouble setting up a simple website with different webpages and staying DRY.

I have everything set up so I the last fragment of the url is the name of the template that needs to be loaded in the content part of the webpage. All I want to do now is load that template in a specific location based on the url.

In any examples, they do this:

```
{{#if showCreateDialog}}
    {{> createDialog}}
  {{/if}}

  {{#if showInviteDialog}}
    {{> inviteDialog}}
  {{/if}}
```

I'd like to do something along the lines of

```
{{> {{template_name}} }}
```

Sadly, that doesnt work. I tried this as well:

```
{{{content}}}

Template.content.content = function () {
var url_frag = Session.get("url_frag");
return Template[url_frag]();
}
```

This didnt work either. Please help!

Edit:

hmm. perhaps, my error is not in loading the template but in capturing the url:

```
var TodosRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "*url": "main"
    },
    main: function (url) {
        Session.set("url", url.split('/'))
    }
});
```

The error I am getting arises when url_frag is undefined...

```
var url_frag = Session.get("url_frag");
```

initially, this works, but upon changing webpages, it fails...

Comment: I think your use of Template[name](), combined with {{{}}} should work.

Here's an example of this is use: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-ui-unstyled/login_buttons_dialogs.js#L223 and https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-ui-unstyled/login_buttons_dialogs.html#L71

Comment: thanks for the help. check out my edit. I may have pinpointed the bug to be elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Solved. I just left backbone out of it

```
Template.content.content = function () {
var url = window.location.pathname.split('/');
var url_frag = url.pop()
return Template[url_frag]();
```

Then in the html:

```
<template name="content">
    {{{content}}}
</template>
```

Comment: But this will cause a full page reload, not?

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the router smart package at atmosphere, which also supports complex routes and filters.

https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/router

1. Install `meteorite` using `npm install -g meteorite`
2. Install `router` using `mrt add router`
3. Add `{{renderPage}}` to body
4. Tada! `/login` now renders `{{> login}}`
5. Read the document here: https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router